# ColorOS 6 unknown permission "reading App-Info"

Tags: android, android-permissions

If I install my app on a Realme 5 Pro (ColorOS 6) the app needs access to thirdparty apps by enabling the permission "reading app information" (the permission name is translated from german, but I assume it's correct).

I don't know to which permission this correlates in my manifest and why the user has to set this permission to be able to use the app.

Comment: What APIs are failing?

Comment: @GabeSechan To be honest, this happens on the device of a user and the only thing that I know is that he gets an toast at the start of the app, telling that (translation from german): `TheAppName` was forbidden to access information from third party apps. You can allow this...